# How to save each file in request.FILES with for loop in Django?

Tags: python, django

Okay so I've looked at many of the answers on the internet but none seem to solve this problem. I'm trying to save each from a multifile upload but it keeps saving the same file f number of times. Something with my 'form' attribute is causing this problem but i can't seem to figure out why.

### views.py

```
def upload_book(request):
if request.method == 'POST':  
    for f in request.FILES.getlist('pdf'):
        form = BookForm()
        form = BookForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return redirect('book_list')
else:
    form = BookForm()
return render(request, 'upload_book.html', {
    'form': form
})
```

### forms.py

```
    class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Book
            fields = ('pdf',)
            widgets = {
                'pdf': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
            }
```

### models.py

```
    class Book(models.Model):
        pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='books/pdfs/')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title

        def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.pdf.delete()
            super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in the `for` loop?

Comment: @KlausD. I'm trying to update the form with each uploaded file which then gets saved.

Comment: First, you are creating two `BookForm` instances. Secondly I would expect that you are using `f` somewhere in the loop if that is your loop variable.

Comment: You should show the code for BookForm and its model (presumably Book). Does it expect multiple files?

Comment: Yes I've tried using 'f' everywhere not exactly sure where to put it anymore. I want to save each file using the loop but currently only saves the first file 'f' times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to solve my problem by creating an instance of BookForm and submitting the data through the loop. Hope this helps somebody else in the future.

### Views.py

```
    def upload_book(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    for f in request.FILES.getlist('pdf'):
        form = BookForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.pdf = f
            obj.save()
    return redirect('book_list')
else:
    form = BookForm()
return render(request, 'upload_book.html', {
    'form': form
})
```

Comment: great answer, this helped so much! Why hasn't anyone else done this yet? Did no one really need to do a multi file upload in a form?

Comment: Its strange that you still get a list of files with request.FILES.get but you can't loop over it. You NEED to have request.files.getlist to get a list of files. Weird behavior.